# Replace existing master for personal repo with a completely new set of files

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a personal git repository. I want to replace the existing remote master files (on github or bitbucket) with a completely new project (fresh attempt for the same project).

I deleted the existing folder for the project on my computer. Then I created a new folder and some new files for the fresh attempt.

How can I make replace my existing remote master with these new files?

In the new folder, I did `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit -m "a completely different attempt"`. But then what do I need to do? I tried with `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git` and `git push origin master`, but that gave an error message (I tried to follow the suggestion made in the error message, but that only led to new error messages)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if, when you are asking a question that involves an error message, that you include the exact error message in the question.  Given what you are doing (trying to replace the history of your remote repository with your local repository), you would expect to see the following error:

```
To github.com:larsks/someproject.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:larsks/someproject.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This happens because you are trying to *replace* history, rather than simply update it with a new set of changes.  This isn't something you want to to by accident, because it will result in lost data (i.e., some or all of the history of your project).  However, this is exactly what you want, so you need to use the `--force` (`-f`) option:

```
git push -f
```

Which should result in something like:

```
[...]
+ 2a49b3d...3d1e101 master -> master (forced update)
```

An alternative solution, of course, is just to delete and then re-create the remote repository.

Comment: That did work :) It would, of course, be nice to have the old attempt in history just for fun, but that is of less importance for me. Thanks!

Comment: You could always keep the old history in a different branch.